# Как найти причину двух редиректов на странице?

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, seo

При проверке сайта программой WebSite Auditor она выдает предупреждение:

"На сайте найдены страницы, у которых настроено более 2-х редиректов. " И далее в табличке указаны эти самые url.

Если например перейти по одному из них, наблюдаю следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Действительно происходит два редиректа.

Я не могу понять где эта прога нашла подобные ссылки, их не много , всего 8 штук.

В htaccess есть только один редирект

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Больше нечего нет, кто нибудь сталкивался с таким ? И как это можно поправить ? Куда копать дальше? Буду рад любым рекомендациям.

Comment: А вы не в .htaccess смотрите, а в настройки nginx :Р

Comment: Я проверил указанную ссылку (возможно вы можете указывать проблемные ссылки явно) с инструментом Redirect Checker. Там нет переадресации - http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Comment: Хм, спасибо, возможно какой то глюк у WebSite Auditor

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решилась , оказалось что эти ссылки были в статьях на сайте и вбиты были как абсолютные http://mydomen.ru/link/ я исправил их и все стало нормально.

Answer (score -1):

Автор, если проблема всё ещё актуальна, советую попробовать нетпик Spider или тот же скримин фрог, у нетпик Спайдера есть триал, на решение проблемы времени хватит. Очень просто и "на пальцах" прослеживается ветка редиректов.

Comment: Наверняка проблема будет актуальна не только автору первоначального вопроса. Не могли бы расписать ваше решение чуть подробнее?